# Too much vertical space above \xrightarrow

Tags: spacing, symbols, stacking-symbols

I currently have the following shortcut in my LaTeX document for an isomorphism arrow:

```
\usepackage{kpfonts,Baskervaldx,mathrsfs,calligra}

\newcommand{\congto}{\xrightarrow{\sim}}
```

This works fine, except for the fact that there is a bit too much vertical space below the `\sim`.
In particular, if the arrow happens to appear below any other inline maths, then things seem a little bit too squished.
How can I lower the `\sim` to be closer to my `\xrightarrow`?

Here is how things look at the moment:

[image: current situation]

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/231785/reduce-vertical-space-for-xrightarrow, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/419965/center-label-text-over-xrightarrow-with-scaled-stackrel/420491#420491

Answer (score 3):

Following the links in a comment, I just used

```
\newcommand{\congto}{\xrightarrow{\raisebox{-1ex}[0ex][0ex]{$\sim$}}}
```

which worked great:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you don't need it in `\scriptstyle` (though I think `\xrightarrow` only comes in `\textstyle`), then

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kpfonts,Baskervaldx,mathrsfs,calligra}
\newcommand{\congto}{\altxrightarrow{\sim}}
\usepackage{stackengine,amsmath}
\newcommand\altxrightarrow[2][0pt]{\mathrel{\ensurestackMath{\stackengine%
  {\dimexpr#1-7.5pt}{\xrightarrow{\phantom{#2}}}{\scriptstyle\!#2\,}%
  {O}{c}{F}{F}{S}}}}
\begin{document}
$A\congto B$

$A\altxrightarrow{\equiv} B$

$A\altxrightarrow[-2pt]{\mathrm{wth}} B$
\end{document}
```

[image]

`\altxrightarrow` thrown in for free.